# Can I trigger the Vuforia app camera through a button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Can I trigger the vuforia app camera through a button? I would like the app startup to enter a login page instead of the direct camera.

I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is **split the work into multiple scenes**, but also make use of the **Delayed Initialization** option in the **Vuforia Settings**, because even if you divide the work into multiple scenes (for example a scene for the login page, and then a scene for vuforia), Vuforia will still be initialized regardless and this can slow your first scene down.

Enable it and then Vuforia won't be initialized until you call its method in a script.

Here is an example of a code that you can use to initialize Vuforia once you load its scene:

```
// Optional: execute before your other scripts in the scene
[DefaultExecutionOrder(-1)]
public class VuforiaInitializer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Initialize on awake
    private void Awake()
    {
        VuforiaApplication.Instance.Initialize();
    }
}
```

More about scene loading can be found here: (Async method is preferred)

[Sync Loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

[Async Loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

You can also call this from a button if you would like to wrap it in a public function instead.

Hope this helps!